# Using USB RFID reader input with background processing

Tags: c#, winforms, background-process, hid, rfid

I have a varsity project where I have to use a RFID reader in the background to keep track of Employee Clock-in/out. The foreground winform GUIs deals with everyday transaction such as Orders, quotes, etc. So I need to be able to use the program without interruption while simultaneously keeping track of employees coming and going. I've looked into Background workers, some kind of new tread and input grabbing. But I just can't seem to find anything that will work. The RFID reader acts as a keyboard and I can get its name. using  [Raw Input](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard)

RFID details:[image: RFID Reader Details]

To clarify, the user must be able to use the program (multiple forms) without interruption while any input from the RFID reader must be recorded in a background list.

I am new to background workers, multi- threading and input grabbing so I will appreciate some detailed help. Also please ask if you need more detail from my side.

Comment: Do you have some codes ? Without any codes, this will be too broad...

Comment: Have you already successfully read some RFIDs in C# with your device? Then please post the code you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

The RFID reader I have here, a NordicID Sampo comes with an API which fires up a thread which reads the data. You can build on that by creating a Task which reads data from a buffer added by that thread. Then you can pass that data to a Form or email it or whatever.

Your scanner probably has a likewise mechanism.

**Example:** StartStreaming is a wrapper around the device's API which fires up the thread reading the device's data.

```
    class RFIDReader : IDisposable
    {
        public void StartStreaming()
        {
            if (RFID_ConnectSerialPort(mAPIHandle, 4, 115200) == 0 || RFID_ConnectAutoUSB(mAPIHandle) == 0)
            {
                RFID_StartInventoryStreaming(
                    (value, antenna) => {
                        mAntennas[antenna].Add(value);
                    });
            }
        }
/////// MORE FUNCTIONS
    }
```

Client code which fires up its own task and checking for data periodically:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action a = new Action(() =>
    {
        using (RFIDReader scanner = new RFIDReader())
        {
            scanner.StartStreaming();

            while (true)
            {
                foreach (string s in scanner.GetData(0))
                {
                    WriteLine($"antenna0: {s}");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    });
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(a);

    t.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Consider using [Task.ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks](https://blog.ciber.no/2014/05/19/using-task-configureawaitfalse-to-prevent-deadlocks-in-async-code/).

Comment: Then you need .NET 4.5, in production code I would save the SynchronizationContext and use that for updating the GUI nut yeah in 4.5 just call ConfigureWait

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [LibUsbDotNet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/)
You could react on the [DataReceivedEvent](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/2ae01ee5-96c2-e3f4-b598-06cf3578a00e.htm). So you would avoid blocking while polling for new data. If you chose the polling aproach @Servé already showed you how to send it to another task to avoid blocking the main thread.

So here is the Suggested Solution with the DataReceivedEvent.

Initialize the USB Device:

```
   IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = PhysicalLibUSBDevice as IUsbDevice;
    if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
    {
        // This is a "whole" USB device. Before it can be used, 
        // the desired configuration and interface must be selected.

        // Select config #1
        wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);

        // Claim interface #0.
        wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(0);
    }


    // Create the reader and writer streams
    _libUsbReader = PhysicalLibUSBDevice.OpenEndpointReader(LibUsbDotNet.Main.ReadEndpointID.Ep01);
    _libUsbWriter = PhysicalLibUSBDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(LibUsbDotNet.Main.WriteEndpointID.Ep02);

    _libUsbReader.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;
    _libUsbReader.DataReceivedEnabled = true;
    _libUsbReader.ReadThreadPriority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;
    _libUsbReader.ReadBufferSize = 32;
```

Define the Eventhandler:

```
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, EndpointDataEventArgs e)
{
    //Use the Buffer and Count Properties of the EventArgs to get the received data        
    Console.WriteLine("Data received");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi threading isn't very easy. BackgroundWorker is somewhat easier on the GUI, but it is still hard to access the GUI from within the background task. Why not try first with the `Task/Await` ? This avoids multithreading, and still can run two tasks.

Comment: Given he is using .NET 4.5 which supports async/await. If he is using earlier .NET versions he needs some Library like AsyncBridge. Even when Async/await and Task simplify parallel programming its still multithreading. Before using multithreading to poll the RFID Reader i would suggest trying to react to Recieved Event of the USB Device if the used USB lib supports this.

Comment: True. I would not go with old versions of .Net. Task took me a while to get the concepts, but now I like it a lot better than real multithreading.